# Ansible dynamic inventory missing from github repo

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I was checking this documentation
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#inventory-script-example-aws-ec2

and found that EC2 dynamic inventory is not available in github repo and other inventories are also not available.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py

There is no information in Ansible release notes or anywhere. Even looks like documentation is also not up-to-date. Please share if anyone has any information about this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, official documentation is not updated and the links are resulting in 404.
I just checked official Ansible repository on Github and found that required folder is not present in "devel" branch.

However, you can still get the required ec2.py and ec2.ini files from "stable" branches.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.9/contrib/inventory/ec2.ini
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.9/contrib/inventory/ec2.py

Answer (score 0):

This is a new inventory repo

https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/tree/main/scripts/inventory

see oficial documentation

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#other-inventory-scripts

Comment: Move to this repo https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws

Comment: Where in there is the ec2.py and ec2.ini? https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/tree/main/plugins/modules - shows the ec2.py - but the ini file? It also doesn't look very stable at this point in time either. Is the build failing? See the Readme.md